# Counting the number of upper triangular matrices in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> How many matrices are in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ are upper triangular? How many upper triangular matrices with 1 on the diagonal are there?

$\textbf{proof.}$
Let $U$ be the subgroup of upper triangular matrices of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and let $D$ be the subgroup of upper triangular matrices with diagonal entries 1.

To find the order of $U$, we note that the diagonal entries can never by zero, since if one diagonal entry was zero the resulting matrix wouldn't be invertible. Also a row in an invertible upper triangular matrix will never be a multiple of a row above it, since the diagonal entry of the preceding row can only be zeroed out by multiplying the row by zero. Thus
$$
\lvert U \rvert
= (p-1)p^{n-1} \cdot (p-1)p^{n-2} \cdot \ldots \cdot (p-1)
= (p-1)^n p^{1 + 2 + \ldots + n-1}
= (p-1)^n p^{n(n-1)/2}.
$$

To find the order of $D$ we divide out the nonzero diagonal entries
$$
\lvert D \rvert
= \frac{\lvert U \rvert}{(p-1)^n} = p^{n(n-1)/2}.
$$
//

Is this correct and is it articulated alright? If there are other ways of counting this I'd like to know as well, thanks.

Comment: $U$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042902/sylow-p-subgroups-of-gl-n-mathbbf-p?rq=1).

Comment: The proof is correct. You don't need the "Also a row in an invertible upper triangular matrix will never be a multiple of a row above it" sentence, though.